# Gram Schmidt Process for functions

Tags: equation-solving

I want to implement the Gram Schimdt procedure to the space of functions in the following form
\begin{align}‎
‎R(y,x)=\left\{‎
‎\begin{array}{ll}‎
f(x,y), ‎& y\leq x\\ \\‎
g(x,y), ‎& y>x‎
‎\end{array}‎
‎\right.
‎\end{align}‎
the inner product is defined as
‎\begin{align}‎
‎\langle u‎ ,‎v\rangle= u(a) v(a)+\int_a^b u^{'}(x) v^{'}(x)dx‎, ‎\qquad \|u\|^2=\langle u‎ ,‎u\rangle‎
‎\end{align}‎
I couldn't implement it in Matlab and I am an amateur in Mathematica, so are there anybody to help me?

Comment: I did implement Gram-Schmidt for functions in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22040/gram-schmidt-process-for-polynomials/22045#22045). It may be not the best implementation, but you can use it as a starting point.

Comment: How can I define function R(y,x) in Mathematica?

Comment: @D.N.S you can try rr[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{ff[x, y], y <= x}, {gg[x, y], x > y}}]; Orthogonalize[{{1, 1}}, rr, Method -> "GramSchmidt"]